# React.js : Discard unused variables in setContext

Tags: reactjs

In my Context.js file, I am passing multiple state variables:

```
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={[searchResult, setSearchResult, currentProduct, setCurrentProduct, apiKey, userId, setUserId]}>
      {props.children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
```

And in a specific component, I am using only the userId and setUserId elements. To receive these variables, I do:

```
let [searchResult, setSearchResult, currentProduct, setCurrentProduct, apiKey, userId, setUserId] = useContext(Context);
```

The question is: is there a way to receive only userId and setUserId in this component without having to declare all the other unused variables as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change how you're passing the value from an array to an object.

```js
return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ searchResult, setSearchResult, currentProduct, setCurrentProduct, apiKey, userId, setUserId }}>
      {props.children}
    </Context.Provider>
);

let { userId, setUserId } = useContext(...)
```

If you don't want to change it, you can use the index but I wouldn't recommend it.

```
let context = useContext(...)
let userId = context[5]
let setUserId = context[6]
```